# Eclipse Project not working in Jenkins

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, executable-jar

I have a Maven Project that creates a table in AWS DynamoDB and push few values to it. This project is built in Eclipse. But when I try to do a Maven build of same project in Jenkins, the Build Status is successful. But no table is getting created in DynamoDB. Is it because the created `.jar` file after build in Jenkins is not getting executed? In that case, I tried to add a `batch` command to execute the created `.jar` file as `java -jar "samples-1.0.0.jar"`. Then, I am getting an error as `no main manifest attribute, in samples-1.0.0.jar`. Why is this not happening in Jenkins while it works fine with Eclipse ?

Comment: 1> Try to run that Batch command from CMD and find whether Jenkins and CMD giving the same error. 
2> Check whether the jar file is in the same location as your workspace. Because Jenkins takes the files from Workspace or you need to give the absolute path of the jar file.